# Accessing Registry.LocalMachine on 64bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have some code below that is accessing the registry.  The application is built for x86 but when run on a 64bit OS it does not find the registry key.  I thought that if it was compiled for x86 it would be ok and not try to look in the Wow6432Node node.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just that on a 64bit OS the registry keys should be under the Wow6432Node node?

```
RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Inspectron\ImageChecker");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ram confirmed that the keys in the registry has to be in the Wow6432node and I then found that compiling as x86 and using the code I already had meant that it would look under the Wow6432node for the keys.

Answer (score 1):

> is it just that on a 64bit OS the registry keys should be under the Wow6432Node node?

Yes.. That's right.. 64bit OS (Windows) stores 32 bit application's keys only inside the Wow6432Node.

Hence you have to look for your key inside the Wow6432node's registry hive.

Answer (score 0):

In 'Run' give 'regedit' String u'll get registry list